# How to determine file-encoding of file on hdfs (Azure blob storage)?

Tags: azure, hadoop, hdfs, azure-blob-storage, file-encodings

I've got a bunch of 100GB files on hdfs with mixed file-encodings (unfortunately in Azure blob storage).  How can I determine the file encodings of each file?  Some dfs command-line command would be ideal. Thanks.

Comment: Did you set the "Content-Encoding" when uploading the files? If yes, you can get it from the properties of the blobs. If no, you can get part of a blob as binary, and use an encoding detection program to guess the encoding of the blob. Here is a python package for detecting encoding: [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up getting the results I needed by piping the beginning of each file in blob storage to a local buffer and then applying the `file` unix utility.  Here's what the command looks like for an individual file:

```
hdfs dfs -cat wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/file | head -n 10 > buffer; file -i buffer
```

This gets you something like:

```
buffer: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-install/

The command `azure storage blob list` and `azure storage blob show` will return all the available blob properties including contentType, contentLength, metadata.

If this information doesn't contain what you want - file-encodings, I think you need to define/set your own `metadata` like `file-encoding` for each files. Then you can retrieve it back via the CLI tool.